Is it possible to remove SERVER respone header from AWS Amplify app
I have a react app.. hosted on amplify. It seems amplify uses cloudfront behind the scene so static content are served with header 'Server: S3'.
I want to remove this via customhttp.yml however, cloudfront ignores this custom header and adds up its own header. Is there any way to remove it for Amplify app
